# Razor Page - Custom Component TagHelper (not Blazor)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am working on a traditional aspnetcore (.net5) website that is configured to use razor pages (.cshtml)

I have also in a separate project been working on Blazor (.razor). When creating a component for Blazor, I can reference it in a page with a tag of the component name:

```html
<MyComponent Property="value" />
```

Are there any examples of how to do this same method referencing a standard razor component within a standard razor project. At the moment, I have to do it through the `component` tag which isn't anywhere near as nice:

```html
<component type="typeof(MyComponent)" param-Property="value" render-mode="..." />
```

I assume this is some form of TagHelper, but am failing in my searches to find any examples - Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help you get started, it seems like your razor (MVC) components need to inherit a class and override some of its methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-5.0